# Mako giving SyntaxError on valid code?

Tags: python, syntax-error, mako

I'm trying to use a block of code within a mako template, yet no matter what I put in the block, Mako is adamant it's a syntax error.

Here's a snippet of the block in question:

```
  <td class="col_sm_space">&nbsp;</td>
  <%
      if session.dist == "metric":
          delta_distance = "%.2fkm" % (trk["d_distance"] / 1000.0)
          delta_fuel = "%.2fl" % (trk["d_fuel"])
          delta_co2 = "%.2fg" % (trk["d_co2"])
          delta_co2_rate = "%.2fg/l" % trk["d_co2_rate"])
          trip_av_speed = "%dkm/h" % int(trk["trip_av_speed"])
          trip_peak_speed = "%dkm/h" % int(trk["trip_peak_speed"])
  %>
  <td class="col_field" title="${delta_distance}">${trk["trip_distance"]}</td>
```

I'm getting the syntax error on the `if session.dist == "metric":` line, although I could replace this with anything (Such as `foo = "bar"`) and it still gives me the error.

Mako is returning:

`SyntaxException: (SyntaxError) invalid syntax (line 5) ('if session.dist == "metric":\\n    delta_distance = ') in file '<snipped>' at line: 271 char: 9\n, referer: <snipped>`

Line `271` is the opening `<%`. Char `9` would be the beginning of the `if` on the next line, apparently.

Oddly, I'm using this exact same setup on other pages, and it's fine with those - just not here.

Anything glaringly obvious I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you have any invisible characters in the lines in question? Or different newline characters than in the other working files?

Comment: Nope, same format. Unix line endings, no extra whitespace at end of lines, and no tabs (Indentation is 4 spaces).

Answer (score 2):

I had a really frustrating experience with this. In my case, at least, the error report was just completely wrong. It pointed to the first line of a python block, like yours, when the actual error was in a different python block, 50 lines later.

Likely, you have a simple syntax error like bad indentation or a missing colon after an if statement... I can't give you any better debugging advice than going through your python with a fine-toothed comb. If it's possible to unit-test your python blocks outside of Mako, that might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

My experience was that I had this if syntax:

```
% if ${use_force_ssl} == 1:
```

Instead, it was supposed to be like this:

```
% if use_force_ssl == 1:
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

This was asked a very long time ago but for the record there is a missing left paren, "(",  on this line, its not clear if that is causing the problem but it seems likely:

```
delta_co2_rate = "%.2fg/l" % trk["d_co2_rate"])
```

Should be at least:

```
delta_co2_rate = "%.2fg/l" % (trk["d_co2_rate"])
```

Answer (score 1):

In mako templates,
when you are using a conditional statement eg if, for etc, it should be like this: 
% if condition
      some code
%endif
And for assigment, you have to embed that thing in `<%   %>`
If you will follow this, your code will run.